# gatsby : optimize images that do not have 'childImageSharp' graphql field

Tags: image, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image, dynamic-image-generation

I am using gatsby with a wordpress CMS to display upcoming events on my gatsby web app .I am using the plugin `gatsby-source-tribe-events` to connect to the `wordpress event calendar` plugin and get the event data.

The problem is that I want to dynamically display all my events with their description and images using `<GatsbyImage/>`.

As you know to display the image with the above component , there has to be a `childImageSharp` field in `graphql` for every item

[image]

My problem is that the `gatsby-source-tribe-events` plugin does not have a `childImageSharp` field when querying for an image ,  so I cannot dynamically get all images OPTIMIZED

[image]

What is a workaround to this ? How can I use GatsbyImage when the childImageSharp field is  not there ? Is there a way to add it to the graphql schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a workaround to this ? How can I use GatsbyImage when the
> childImageSharp field is not there ?

You can't. `GatsbyImage` needs a certain amount of data provided by the `childImageSharp` node.

[`gatsby-source-tribe-events`](https://github.com/erinoerin/gatsby-source-tribe-events) plugin seems quite unmaintained (last commit 2 years ago) so I don't think the author upgrades it.

Said that you have two options (at least):

- Render the standard `<img>` tag if you detect an image that doesn't contain the `childImage` node. There you can apply lazy loading or any other blur effect with another library.
- Checking [`gatsby-plugin-remote-images`](http://%20https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-remote-images/) to create nodes from remote images. I don't know if this approach fits your requirements or if it's doable.

> Is there a way to add it to the graphql schema ?

This is what `gatsby-plugin-remote-images` will do. Images need to be treated by Gatsby's transformers and sharps to create those `childImageSharp` nodes